# WW1 Uniform - Which country does this uniform belong to?

Tags: europe, world-war-one, uniform

[image: ww1 uniform]

Please help me identify this ww1 uniform.

Comment: Any and all information you might have would be of assistance in the identification. Do you know anything at all about the picture?

Comment: Any chance that it is a Firemen's uniform rather than a soldier's?

Comment: Agreed to @PieterGeerkens he looks like belonging to some more civil service like Fireman or Police force. But judging the badge, it contains axe and helmet, looks like fireman.

Comment: Gentleman - you have truely helped me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having searched around the suggestions above, I eventually found this badge that is listed as a Imperial Russian Fire Society badge. As you can see, there are several similarities between it and the badge in your picture; the helmet and crossed axes mainly.

[image: Imperial Russian fire Society]

So, I'd agree with the others when saying that it appears to be the uniform of a Russian firefighter in the years leading to the revolution.

Comment: Given that the badge he is wearing has the letters FD in Roman characters rather than Cyrillic I would be inclined to doubt that the photo is of a Russian fire-man. Also the helmet and crossed fire axes is a common fire service device from the early 20th century. You will find a button with exactly this device [here](http://www.belowstairs.co.uk/acatalog/DSCF1933A.jpg) which from its context and what is stamped on the back we may assume is British. The abbreviation FD would suggest to me an English speaking place of origin, probably in the New-World.

Comment: Also the absence of a crown and oak leaves suggests that the pin is not from any of the continental European Empires: Britain, Germany, Russia and Austria-Hungary.

Comment: I can imagine it might be Russian, but in Imperial Russia there were several nations who used latin alphabet (Polish, Finnish, Baltic nations), the badge itself could belong to Imperial Russian Fire Society while they use latin letters for district or something.

Comment: WOW - I think both asnwers are correct. This is pre or around WW1. I have no clue where it is from though. Its either Ukraine, France, or Belarus. This is my great great grandfather and I am trying to pin point where he was born. His origin is from either Belarus or Ukraine but we also know that for a portion of time he lived in Paris ~ probably do to the jewish pogroms that took place in 1880's.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fireman. If FD is for "fire department", he was a fireman probably somewhere in the US. Is the 2016 his badge ID?

Comment: He wasnt in US. My family did not move to US until 1992. It must be somewhere in Europe/Easter Europe.

Comment: What one could look for is the badge, the little, separate, oval tag below it with the number, and the collar and the jacket pockets. "FD" is the common English abbreviation for "fire department", although you say it can't be in the US. The jacket collar looks a bit like a French army coat collar from around World War 1, and the jacket pocket look like these [pockets] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_J._Pershing#mediaviewer/File:John_Pershing.jpg , although the pockets are at an angle.

Comment: "FD" can't be his initials, or can they? Common names can, considering he was Jewish, be found here: http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2014/01/08/ashkenazi_names_the_etymology_of_the_most_common_jewish_surnames.html